# Best way to handle transaction errors?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, transactions

What's the best way to handle transaction errors in Asp.net core and entity framework?

At this time I have come with something like:

```
using (var transaction = _dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        await _dbContext.MyTable1.AddAsync(table1Entity);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        Entity2 e2 = new Entity2();
        e2.Table1Id = table1Entity.Id;
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        await transaction.CommitAsync();

        return new CreatedAtRouteResult(...);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Console.Write(ex);
        await transaction.RollbackAsync();

        var context = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();

        return Problem(
            detail: context.Error.StackTrace,
            title: context.Error.Message);
    }
}
```

But don't really know if this is a good practice. How would you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code was good, except you don't need to call:

```
await transaction.RollbackAsync();
```

in catch block. Failed transaction will auto-rollback when disposed.

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the way you are handling the transactions, but there are some improvements you can make here:

1. Remove the data access code from your controller and move it into a separate class.
2. Do not return the technical details of the error, but a user friendly message.
3. AddAsync only exists for special use cases, all other cases should use the non-async method Add.

From the [EF docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.addasync?view=efcore-3.1):

> "This method is async only to allow special value generators, such as
>   the one used by
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.SequenceHiLo',
>   to access the database asynchronously. For all other cases the non
>   async method should be used."

Comment: Could you comment when should I use AddAsync? I thouht it was googd practice to try to make all calls asynchronous.